# $ne to check two fields in MongoDb using golang (mgo)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am using go lang in the back end and mongoDB as my database.In my mgo pipeline i m selecting some values from my mongoDB. Below is the go lang equivalent condition which is working

```
if status !="Processing"{
//then select or project the values
}
```

The mgo query is as follows and this is working

```
pipe10 := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
            {
                "$unwind": "$" + type,
            },
            {
                "$match": bson.M{
                    type + ".status": bson.M{
                        "$ne": "Processing",
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                "$project": bson.M{
                    "name": 1,
                },
            },
        },
        )
```

but when i try to add another value for $ne this is not working.This doesnt throw error but just it skips this != condition.
 Below is the go lang equivalent condition which i need to implement and  not working

```
if status !="Processing" || status !="Denied{
    //then select or project the values
    }
```

I tried as following in mgo

```
 1.   pipe10 := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
                    {
                        "$unwind": "$" + type,
                    },
                    {
                        "$match": bson.M{
                            type + ".status": bson.M{
                                "$ne":[]interface{"Processing","Denied"}
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "$project": bson.M{
                            "name": 1,
                        },
                    },
                },
                )
  2.   pipe10 := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
                    {
                        "$unwind": "$" + type,
                    },
                    {
                        "$match": bson.M{
                            type + ".status": bson.M{
                                "$ne":bson.M{
                              "$in":[]interface{"Processing","Denied"}
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "$project": bson.M{
                            "name": 1,
                        },
                    },
                },
                ) 
 3.   pipe10 := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
                    {
                        "$unwind": "$" + type,
                    },
                    {
                        "$match": bson.M{
                            type + ".status": bson.M{
                                "$ne":bson.M{
                              "$or":[]interface{"Processing","Denied"}
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "$project": bson.M{
                            "name": 1,
                        },
                    },
                },
                )
```

But these are not working.Appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried not in ($nin) ? `type + ".status": bson.M{
                                "$nin":[]interface{"Processing","Denied"}
                            }`

Comment: Thanks Claverie.It worked......